# c# Serialize a ObservableCollection ignoring a property

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, observablecollection

I am developing an UWP app using the Creators Update SDK.
I am trying to serialize a `ObservableCollection` ignoring a property of their class.

Here is my code, it have my class and the methods to serialize, you can see I am using  `[DataContract]` and `[IgnoreDataMember]` but it's not working.

```
public class Classes
    {
        [DataContract]
        public class Car : BindableBase
        {
            [DataMember]
            private string _Name;
            public string Name
            {
                get { return _Name; }
                set { Set(ref _Name, value); }
            }

            [DataMember]
            private string _Brand;
            public string Brand
            {
                get { return _Brand; }
                set { Set(ref _Brand, value); }
            }

            [IgnoreDataMember]
            private bool _Electric;
            public bool Electric
            {
                get { return _Electric; }
                set { Set(ref _Electric, value); }
            }

            [DataMember]
            private double _Price;
            public double Price
            {
                get { return _Price; }
                set { Set(ref _Price, value); }
            }
        }

        public class Values_Car : ObservableCollection<Car> { }

        public static class Garage
        {
            public static Values_Car Cars = new Values_Car();

            static Garage()
            {
            }
        }

        [XmlRoot("Root")]
        public class GarageDTO
        {
            [XmlElement]
            public Values_Car Cars { get { return Garage.Cars; } }
        }
    }

   public class NewSerialization
    {
        private static void FillList()
        {
            Car e_1 = new Car()
            {
                Name = "element_Name",
                Brand = "element_Brand",
                Electric = true,
                Price = 1,
            };
            Car e_2 = new Car()
            {
                Name = "element_Name",
                Brand = "element_Brand",
                Electric = true,
                Price = 2,
            };

            Garage.Cars.Add(e_1);
            Garage.Cars.Add(e_2);
        }

        public static string Serializer()
        {
            FillList();

            var _Instance = new GarageDTO();

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GarageDTO));

            using (var stream_original = new MemoryStream())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stream_original, _Instance);

                string string_original = string.Empty;

                stream_original.Position = 0;

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream_original, Encoding.Unicode))
                {
                    string_original = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                return string_original;
            }
        }
    }
```

using `NewSerialization.Serializer();` I got:
But in the xml I got the `Electric` property which is ignored.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Cars>
    <Name>element_Name</Name>
    <Brand>element_Brand</Brand>
    <Electric>true</Electric>
    <Price>1</Price>
  </Cars>
  <Cars>
    <Name>element_Name</Name>
    <Brand>element_Brand</Brand>
    <Electric>true</Electric>
    <Price>2</Price>
  </Cars>
</Root>
```

How I can  ignoring a property of my  `ObservableCollection` on serialization?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Read [attributes-that-control-xml-serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/attributes-that-control-xml-serialization)

Comment: You are using `XmlSerializer` but `[DataContract]`, `[DataMember]` and `[IgnoreDataMember]` are for [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx).  See [Attributes That Control XML Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/attributes-that-control-xml-serialization) for the relevant attributes.  The one you want is [`[XmlIgnore]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments of @dbc and @Aluan Haddad I found the exact I was finding, this should be my class to achieve that:

```
public class Car : BindableBase
        {
            private string _Name;
            public string Name
            {
                get { return _Name; }
                set { Set(ref _Name, value); }
            }

            private string _Brand;
            public string Brand
            {
                get { return _Brand; }
                set { Set(ref _Brand, value); }
            }

            private bool _Electric;
            [XmlIgnore] //<----This!           
            public bool Electric
            {
                get { return _Electric; }
                set { Set(ref _Electric, value); }
            }

            private double _Price;
            public double Price
            {
                get { return _Price; }
                set { Set(ref _Price, value); }
            }            
        }
```